# Script not logging to log file

Tags: batch-file

trying to get this bat file to work, think I am close... can someone please help?

```
@echo on
for /f "delims=" %%i in ("netstat -anp TCP | find "ESTABLISHED"| find "3389"") do (
      echo %date% %time% %%i >>C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\rdp.csv
      )
pause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running your code without the file redirection?

Try this:

```
@echo on
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('netstat -anp TCP^| find "ESTABLISHED"^| find "3389"') do (
      echo %date% %time% %%i 
      )
pause
```

You needed to escape your pipes and use single quotes in the for loop.